# Check if directory exists and return an array of all those names combined

Tags: php

I have a folder of directories, which looks like this below

[image]

What i'm trying to achieve when I make an ajax post to that index.php file is to get in return

**['collections', 'contact', 'news', 'opening-of-the-halles', 'story']**

I'm a bit new to PHP, so I'm not sure what i'm doing.  What I did so far is something like this,

```
$path = './192.168.0.338888';

$dirs = array();

// directory handle
$dir = dir($path);

while (false !== ($entry = $dir->read())) {
    if ($entry != '.' && $entry != '..') {
       if (is_dir($path . '/' .$entry)) {
            $dirs[] = $entry; 
       }
    }
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($dirs); exit;
```

However, this is what I get in return which is not what i'm looking for

[image]

Comment: So you want all the folders and sub folders, with the latter ones occurring after their respective parents? If you want this over an unknown number of levels, then you likely want a recursive function.

Comment: Not quite sure what the logic of listing `opening-of-the-halles` at the same level as the other directories is…

Comment: It doesn't need to be in any specific order.  Basically this Wordpress plugin generates these static html files, but because of the particular javascript framework I use...I can't use this plugin out of the box.  So, my thought was to just check if the subdirectory exists, and if so...grab the .html instead